# flyway migration hanging with concurrentlly index creation

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using Spring boot 3.2 and Flyway 9.22.3

Now I am facing a issue that when start the service and execute the flyway scripts, it will always hanging on the script where I create a Index with CONCURRENTLY.

This seems to be a known issue of the flyway according to the issue here:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3508
However none of the solution mentioned there works for me. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the discussion threads in related tickets, I think to avoid this issue, two conditions need to be met:

- Flyway 9.19.4 version or higher
- postgresql.transactional.lock set to false